# Adjust jQuery datepicker selected date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to adjust a date selected in jQuery's datepicker. For example, whatever user chooses, change to closest weekend.

Is there a way to do this? Some validation / filtering support. Or maybe it can be done with a help from some other validation library that will track text in the text box, not the datepicker value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is subscribe to the `select` event and change the date:

```
$('.selector').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $(inst).datepicker('getDate'); // Date should be a Date object
        // do some calculation and set the date via:
        $(inst).datepicker('setDate', date);
    }
});
```

*Note: not tested.*